# I Getting error when run this below query : RETURN statements in scalar valued functions must include an argument

Tags: mysql

I am getting this error message

> RETURN statements in scalar valued functions must include an argument

when run this query:

```
create function gender(@gender nvarchar(40))
returns nvarchar(40)
as
begin
(select name,cast(DOB as date) as DOB from datenames where gender = @gender)
return
end
```

Comment: What about the error is unclear? The function says it `returns nvarchar(40)`, but you never tell it what to return. What is it meant to output? Return that.

Answer (score 0):

The write way to create a function in mysql for your example is as follows:

```
DELIMITER \\

create function gender(Igender nvarchar(40))
returns nvarchar(40)

begin

DECLARE customerLevel NVARCHAR(40);

IF EXISTS (select name,cast(DOB as date) as DOB from datenames where gender = Igender) THEN
    SET customerLevel = 'SOMETHING1';
ELSE
    SET customerLevel = 'SOMETHING2';
END IF;
    
RETURN (customerLevel);

end
```

1. No need to `as`
2. No need to `@` before input
3. You need to return something.
4. Don't forget to use DELIMITER.

If you use *phpmyadmin* and has problem with `nvarchar` read this post: [Unrecognize data type nvarchar in database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43801482/14048240) or simply change it to to `varchar`.

Comment: How can a function that `returns varchar(40)` return a dataset with two columns? Also, the OP's function `returns nvarchar(40)`, but you changed that. Not that it's at all evident what they expect it to return... And what is `Igender`?

Comment: Thank you @underscore_d; I change the answer based your nice comment.